# mongodb setdifference between collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following 2 collection in mongodb

```
db.test.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":1,"description":"test"})
db.test.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":2,"description":"test"})
db.test.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":3,"description":"test"})
db.test.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":5,"description":"test"})
db.test.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":6,"description":"test"})
db.test.insert({"Name":"b","keyid":3,"description":"test"})
db.test.insert({"Name":"b","keyid":4,"description":"test"})


db.test1.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":1,"description":"test"})
db.test1.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":2,"description":"test"})
db.test1.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":8,"description":"test"})
db.test1.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":5,"description":"test"})
db.test1.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":6,"description":"test"})
```

I would like to insert documents from test to test1 for key id and name that are not present in test1 which in this case are

```
db.test1.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":3,"description":"test"})
db.test1.insert({"Name":"b","keyid":3,"description":"test"})
db.test1.insert({"Name":"b","keyid":4,"description":"test"})
```

and similary i would like to insert documents from test1 to test for key id and name that are not present in test which in this case is

```
 db.test.insert({"Name":"a","keyid":8,"description":"test"})
```

Basically i am try to perform setdifference between the 2 collection

Currently i am doing

```
db.test.aggregate([
   {"$group" : {_id : {Name:"$Name", keyid:"$keyid"}}}, 
   {"$project" : { Name:"$_id.Name",keyid:"$_id.keyid"}}
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

And

```
db.test1.aggregate([
   {"$group" : {_id : {Name:"$Name", keyid:"$keyid"}}}, 
   {"$project" : { Name:"$_id.Name",keyid:"$_id.keyid"}}
], { allowDiskUse: true })
```

Then performing whether the output in first aggregation pipeline exist in the output of second aggregation pipeline and vice versa .

Is there a better way of doing this using the set operation in mongodb.

Comment: Solution depends on your working set. How many documents you have in both collections?

Comment: at a time it would 50-100k for each user